# What files should Xcode projects track when git commits

Tags: ios, xcode, git, terminal, gitignore

I took over an iOS project completed by objective-c. The project does not use git, and I want to use git to manage it locally.
I performed the following steps, and then when I submitted, I didn't know which files to add to the tracking file. (I created git to ignore files)

**Steps i did**

I opened the terminal and entered the following command:

```
cd /Users/xxx/Desktop/xxx/Myproject

git init

touch .gitignore

open .gitignore    //I manually added the ignore rule in .gitignore and saved

git status    //我没有修改任何代码，而且没有执行 git add ，因为我不知道该添加哪些文件到追踪文件
```

**This is [ignore file](https://www.gitignore.io/api/xcode,objective-c)**

[image: Results of git status]

Should I execute git add .? Or should I choose some additions?

I hope you can tell me the method and reason, I do n’t understand what I found on Google.

Comment: You should push everything aside from `DS_Store`. The `.xcodeproj`, `.xcworkspace`, `gitignore`, `Tests (UI and Unit)`, `ZT`, `Podfile` and `Podfile.lock` files. `.xcodeproj`, `.xcworkspace` and `ZT` cause they are your project files, either the executables to open xcode or the source code. If you dont actually have any Unit and UI tests then it's not necessary. `Podfile` and `Podfile.lock` should be uploaded cause it will allow others to download the dependencies of the project. Some prefer not to upload the `Pods` folder to reduce size of the repo online, but it is more convenient to push it